# AWS Amplify & React - Storage.put return 403 Forbidden

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I've been searching through the web for an answer but was unable to find something ... so I'm trying here. Sorry if the question has already been solved, it would mean I need to fix my search skills !

The idea of my application: a list of item with images that can be browsed by everyone. An admin part allows an authenticated user to create the items (and upload the image).

For this, what I did for the setup:

```
amplify init
amplify add auth
amplify add storage
amplify add api
```

Most of the config are the ones by default. Only for the storage, I configured:

- Unauthenticated roles can read object
- Authenticated roles can create/read/delete/list objects

Now, in my React application, when I do this:
`Storage.put(image.name, image, { level: 'public' })`
I get
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`

The only way I can make this work is by adding the permission of create on the unauthenticated role. But that's not the goal !

I'm sure I'm missing something but I was not able to find what ...

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the problem. The user I used for login was still with a challenge to change the generated password --> not considered as authenticated.

Once the password has been changed, upload can be done !